# React useEffect: Prevent crashing of app when updating state that is required in the dependency array

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am in a situation where I need to update a certain state in the `useEffect`, while depending on the value of the state itself, and had to put it in the dependency array - due to a warning from `eslint-react-hooks`. However, due to the fact that I am updating a state that is present in the dependency array, this causes the app to crash due to what I believe is an infinite loop happening in the `useEffect`.

The example below shows a simple example:

```
const [list, setList] = useState(list);

useEffect(() => {
  const currentList = [...list];
  const newList = currentList.push(newItem);

  setList(newList);
}, [newItem, list]);
```

I have came up with a solution to use the previous state argument in the set state method of the `useState` hook to update accordingly. This effectively removes the need for the dependency in the dependency array.

```
const [list, setList] = useState(list);

useEffect(() => {
  setList((prevList) => {
    const currentList = [...prevList];
    const newList = currentList.push(newItem);

    return newList;
  });
}, [newItem]);
```

I would like to ask if anyone have faced this issue before, and have found a better solution? Thank you!

Comment: Using the function version of setState is exactly the right thing to do. Not only does it fix your dependency problem, it eliminates all possibility that you're interacting with a stale version of the state.

Comment: The problem doesn't exist in the first place with state updater func. Infinite loop could be avoided by tracking changes in "list" and checking that an update is needs

Comment: @EstusFlask I have tried to find a way to track changes in the `list` state. However, the way my method works is that the length of this `list` state would always remain the same, and only the object item in the list would change. This makes tracking changes in this state complicated and inefficient. Thank you so much for your reply anyway!

Answer (score 1):

The general approach of using the setter's callback instead of having to refer to the outer state value is perfectly normal and acceptable. You can slim it down too:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setList(prevList => [...prevList, newItem]);
}, [newItem]);
```

But it's a little bit strange to have a separate `newItem` state that immediately gets merged into the list. Consider if you could merge them together so you only have one stateful variable in the end. Instead of doing

```
setNewItem(theNewItem);
```

do

```
setList(prevList => [...prevList, theNewItem]);
```

and then, wherever else you refer to `newItem`, change it to `list[list.length - 1]` - or do

```
const newItem = list[list.length - 1];
```

in the body of the component.

That approach won't work for *all* situations, but consider whether it'd be applicable to yours.

Comment: The reason why I have a separate `newItem` is that the actual method I am using requires running more functions on the main `list` state, while using the `newItem` variable as an argument. The example I have shown is a minimal example. Thank you so much for your tip anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the list unchanged and use another state to update the ui:

```
const [list, setList] = useState(list);
const [count, setCount] = useState(list.length);

useEffect(() => {
  list.push(newItem);
  setList(list);
  setCount(list.length);
}, [newItem, list]);
```

Comment: This is a good way I believe for array state with lengths that would change. However, might be not be viable if the array state is expected to not have a change in length, but just a change in values of the item within.